# Theme is not working in Octopress for a custom domain

Tags: wordpress, github, dns, octopress

I've recently migrated my blog from Wordpress to Octopress.

URL of blog is:

```
myproject.github.io/octopress
```

Later I added an A-record to DNS settings of my Wordpress site:

```
myexample.com   points to 192.30.252.154
```

**Issue:**
After loading Octopress blog from **myexample.com** in a browser the standard theme doesn't get loaded, whereas from **myproject.github.io** it does. Other media like text, pics etc. is loaded in both cases.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This due to the fact that you're serving from two different url schemes :  `myexample.com` and `username.github.io/octopress`. Here the main difference is the `/octopress` path.

This is supposed to be taken into account in `_config.yml` :

```
# If publishing to a subdirectory as in site.com/project set 'root: /project'
root: /
```

From the `yourdomain.com` point of view, it's supposed to be `/` and from `username.github.io/octopress` point of view, it's supposed to be `/octopress`.

This what break resources loading in one of the cases.

But the main problem here is the mix between custom domain and github url.

You'de better put your `CNAME` file in your `username.github.io` repository, this will make github redirect all request to `username.github.io` to `yourdomain.com`. And all request to `username.github.io/repository` to `yourdomain.com/repository`.

You will have only one url per repository and no more error possible with the octopress config.

By setting the configuration variable `url: http://yoursite.com` you will also solve the canonical problem generated by this double url problem. Because of SEO and duplicate content.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the thorough answer, David.